# Is there a simple cli to probe dns names/queries

Tags: docker, dns

Say there is a FQND : `www.ebay.com`, How do I do a DNSSEC query to **LIST ALL** for a CNAME without installing any special modules/packages?

Ideally I would like an open-source code to do the same.

I need a VISUAL representation for the data + JSON data set

Comment: `dig` is pretty standard tool. PS: it is *Fully Qualified Domain Name* aka FQDN not FQND

Answer (score -2):

**http://dnsviz.net/**

DNSVIZ is an excellent website for this.

If you have docker installed:

```
docker run -it nrshrivatsan/dnsviz /bin/bash -c "dnsviz probe www.ebay.com"
```

Output would be a JSON, when formatted:

```
.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:55:58 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:55:58 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  explicit_delegation: true
  auth_ns_ip_mapping:
    ns0.:
      - 192.168.65.1
  queries:
    - qname: .
      qclass: IN
      qtype: NS
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              J9yBgAABAA0AAAAAAAACAAEAAAIAAQAAVTgAFAFjDHJvb3Qtc2VydmVycwNuZXQAAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBbcAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBZsAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBa8AeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBYcAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBacAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBYsAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBZ8AeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBZMAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBZcAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBaMAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBbMAeAAACAAEAAFU4AAQBasAe
            msg_size: 228
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: .
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DNSKEY
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 512
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              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
            msg_size: 842
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: .
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DNSKEY
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              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
            msg_size: 842
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
net.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:56:03 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:56:03 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  parent: .
  explicit_delegation: true
  auth_ns_ip_mapping:
    ns0.:
      - 192.168.65.1
  queries:
    - qname: net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: NS
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              XimBgAABAA0AAAAAA25ldAAAAgABwAwAAgABAAA62gARAWEMZ3RsZC1zZXJ2ZXJzwAzADAACAAEAADraAAQBasAjwAwAAgABAAA62gAEAWvAI8AMAAIAAQAAOtoABAFtwCPADAACAAEAADraAAQBYsAjwAwAAgABAAA62gAEAWPAI8AMAAIAAQAAOtoABAFmwCPADAACAAEAADraAAQBZcAjwAwAAgABAAA62gAEAWnAI8AMAAIAAQAAOtoABAFkwCPADAACAAEAADraAAQBbMAjwAwAAgABAAA62gAEAWfAI8AMAAIAAQAAOtoABAFowCM=
            msg_size: 242
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DS
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              d3eBgAABAAEAAAAAA25ldAAAKwABwAwAKwABAADS8QAkjC4IAnhisn9fUW6+GWgERNTOXnYpgZMYQsRl8AI2QB2L2XPu
            msg_size: 69
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DNSKEY
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              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
            msg_size: 441
            time_elapsed: 2
            history: []
    - qname: net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DNSKEY
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 512
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              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
            msg_size: 441
            time_elapsed: 2
            history: []
akamaiedge.net.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:56:03 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:56:03 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  parent: net.
  explicit_delegation: true
  queries:
    - qname: akamaiedge.net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: A
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: NdeBgwABAAAAAAAACmFrYW1haWVkZ2UDbmV0AAABAAE=
            msg_size: 32
            time_elapsed: 46
            history: []
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:56:03 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:56:03 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  parent: net.
  nxdomain_ancestor: akamaiedge.net.
  explicit_delegation: true
  queries:
    - qname: e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: A
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              Kg6BgAABAAEAAAAABWU5NDI4AWIKYWthbWFpZWRnZQNuZXQAAAEAAcAMAAEAAQAAAAsABBfRsWw=
            msg_size: 56
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: AAAA
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: Dn6BgwABAAAAAAAABWU5NDI4AWIKYWthbWFpZWRnZQNuZXQAABwAAQ==
            msg_size: 40
            time_elapsed: 3
            history: []
edgekey.net.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:56:03 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:56:03 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  parent: net.
  explicit_delegation: true
  queries:
    - qname: edgekey.net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: A
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: A+iBgwABAAAAAAAAB2VkZ2VrZXkDbmV0AAABAAE=
            msg_size: 29
            time_elapsed: 87
            history: []
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:55:58 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:56:00 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  parent: net.
  nxdomain_ancestor: edgekey.net.
  explicit_delegation: true
  queries:
    - qname: slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: A
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              dCeBgAABAAIAAAAACHNsb3Q5NDI4BGViYXkDY29tB2VkZ2VrZXkDbmV0AAABAAHADAAFAAEAABf/ABUFZTk0MjgBYgpha2FtYWllZGdlwCbAOwABAAEAAAALAAQX0bFs
            msg_size: 96
            time_elapsed: 2
            history: []
    - qname: slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: AAAA
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: xmCBgwABAAAAAAAACHNsb3Q5NDI4BGViYXkDY29tB2VkZ2VrZXkDbmV0AAAcAAE=
            msg_size: 47
            time_elapsed: 4
            history: []
com.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:55:58 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:55:58 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  parent: .
  explicit_delegation: true
  auth_ns_ip_mapping:
    ns0.:
      - 192.168.65.1
  queries:
    - qname: com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: NS
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              5mWBgAABAA0AAAAAA2NvbQAAAgABwAwAAgABAAA7ZAAUAWYMZ3RsZC1zZXJ2ZXJzA25ldADADAACAAEAADtkAAQBa8AjwAwAAgABAAA7ZAAEAWfAI8AMAAIAAQAAO2QABAFiwCPADAACAAEAADtkAAQBY8AjwAwAAgABAAA7ZAAEAWnAI8AMAAIAAQAAO2QABAFkwCPADAACAAEAADtkAAQBYcAjwAwAAgABAAA7ZAAEAWXAI8AMAAIAAQAAO2QABAFqwCPADAACAAEAADtkAAQBbMAjwAwAAgABAAA7ZAAEAW3AI8AMAAIAAQAAO2QABAFowCM=
            msg_size: 245
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DS
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              cC6BgAABAAEAAAAAA2NvbQAAKwABwAwAKwABAABmJQAkeL0IAuLTyRb23urHMpToJo+1iFBEqDP8VFlYj0qRhM/EGldm
            msg_size: 69
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DNSKEY
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              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
            msg_size: 441
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DNSKEY
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 512
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              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
            msg_size: 441
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
ebay.com.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:55:58 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:55:58 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  parent: com.
  explicit_delegation: true
  auth_ns_ip_mapping:
    ns0.:
      - 192.168.65.1
  queries:
    - qname: ebay.com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: NS
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              bAKBgAABAAcAAAAABGViYXkDY29tAAACAAHADAACAAEAAAktABQDbnMyA3A0NwZkeW5lY3QDbmV0AMAMAAIAAQAACS0AEQJhMwt2ZXJpc2lnbmRuc8ARwAwAAgABAAAJLQAGA25zNMAqwAwAAgABAAAJLQAGA25zM8AqwAwAAgABAAAJLQAGA25zMcAqwAwAAgABAAAJLQAFAmExwEnADAACAAEAAAktAAUCYTLASQ==
            msg_size: 175
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: ebay.com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DS
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: Xs+BgwABAAAAAAAABGViYXkDY29tAAArAAE=
            msg_size: 26
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: ebay.com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DNSKEY
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 512
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: Q0WBgwABAAAAAAAABGViYXkDY29tAAAwAAE=
            msg_size: 26
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
    - qname: ebay.com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: DNSKEY
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: Q0WBgwABAAAAAAAABGViYXkDY29tAAAwAAE=
            msg_size: 26
            time_elapsed: 1
            history: []
www.ebay.com.:
  type: recursive
  stub: false
  analysis_start: '2018-05-13 02:55:56 UTC'
  analysis_end: '2018-05-13 02:55:58 UTC'
  clients_ipv4:
    - 172.17.0.2
  clients_ipv6: []
  parent: ebay.com.
  nxdomain_ancestor: ebay.com.
  explicit_delegation: true
  queries:
    - qname: www.ebay.com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: A
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: >-
              xRKBgAABAAMAAAAAA3d3dwRlYmF5A2NvbQAAAQABwAwABQABAAAATwAfCHNsb3Q5NDI4BGViYXkDY29tB2VkZ2VrZXkDbmV0AMAqAAUAAQAAF/8AFQVlOTQyOAFiCmFrYW1haWVkZ2XARMBVAAEAAQAAAAsABBfRsWw=
            msg_size: 122
            time_elapsed: 2
            history: []
    - qname: www.ebay.com.
      qclass: IN
      qtype: AAAA
      options:
        flags: 256
        edns_version: 0
        edns_max_udp_payload: 4096
        edns_flags: 32768
        edns_options: []
        tcp: false
      responses:
        192.168.65.1:
          172.17.0.2:
            message: +SCBgwABAAAAAAAAA3d3dwRlYmF5A2NvbQAAHAAB
            msg_size: 30
            time_elapsed: 6
            history: []
_meta._dnsviz.:
  version: 1.1
  names:
    - www.ebay.com.
```

**Source**
https://github.com/dnsviz/dnsviz/pull/36